# C# telegram bot getting " a call to SSPI failed " error

Tags: c#, telegram

SO Im creating my first Telegram bot using C# here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace k4rn46ebot{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private static string TOKEN = "";
    private Thread botThread;
    Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient bot;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TOKEN = ttoken.Text;
        botThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(runBot));
        botThread.Start();
    }
    void runBot() {
        bot = new Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient(TOKEN);
        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            lblstatus.Text = "Online";
            lblstatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }));
        int offset = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[] update = bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset).Result;
            foreach (var up in update)
            {
                offset = up.Id + 1;
                if (up.Message == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                var message = up.Message.Text.ToLower();
                var from = up.Message.From;
                var chatid = up.Message.Chat.Id;

                if (message.Contains("/start"))
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.AppendLine(from.Username + "welcome to K4RN46E BOT");
                    bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatid, sb.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        botThread.Abort();
    }
}
```

}

I'm getting the following error: "an unhandled exception of type 'system.aggregateexception' occurred in mscorlib.dll" error on line:Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[] update = bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset).Result;

In the event tab of MS Visual Studio 2015 
I'm getting: "Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException' in System.dll ("A call to SSPI failed, See inner exception.")" and the inner exception says:"Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException' in System.dll ("A call to SSPI failed, See inner exception.")" too.

Can anyone explain why I might be getting this error and what should I do to fix it?
this is my event windows:
[MS Viasual Studio 2015 Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwLdN.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO :) What have you tried to fix this error? Have you looked [at this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336378/a-call-to-sspi-failed-see-inner-exception-when-running-the-call-a-second-time)? And have you checked what the "inner exception" says, as you can see in your stack trace?

Comment: To clarify: it seems there are more than one inner exceptions that may contain useful info

Comment: You need to `await` your async calls too.